# annotation-based validation framework

Tags: java, validation

I'm looking for an annotation-based validation framework, that would allow me to validate parameter values. Something like the following:

```
void someMethod(@NotBlank String foo, @NotEmpty Collection bar, @Positive Integer baz, @NotNull Object obj) {

}
```

Validation of the parameters should happen automatically whenever an annotated method/constructor is called, so that there no way to bypass the validation.

If I could customise the error messages produced that would be nice. I'm using Java 1.5.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try taking a look at [OVal](http://oval.sourceforge.net/) and others implementors of the [JSR-303](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303) (aka Bean validation)

Comment: Yes, OVal seems like a winner to me: http://oval.sourceforge.net/userguide.html#d4e233

Answer (score 7):

That's a job for a [JSR 303 - Bean Validation](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=303) implementation, like [Hibernate Validator](http://www.hibernate.org/subprojects/validator.html) (the RI). Check the various [Bean Validation blog posts](http://in.relation.to/tag/Bean+Validation) from Emmanuel Bernard (the spec lead).

Comment: @Don AFAIK, BV is for Java 1.5+, it doesn't require Java 1.6 (with Hibernate Validator, I know that you'll have to provide the JAXB API and a JAXB implementation if you're using Java 1.5 since it's not part of the JDK).

Comment: Thanks Pascal. I dislike the fact that you need to manually invoke the validation. I would like the params to be automatically validated whenever an annotated method is called.

Comment: +1 Just for the Emmanuel Bernard fandom (listeners of "les castcodeurs" , hands up !)

Comment: @Don I used it hooked in other frameworks (JPA, JSF 2.0, Wicket, etc) so it does the job for me. But I get what you mean. @Riduidel Thanks, and you have my +1 too (didn't try OVal so far, only Hibernate Validator that covers my needs). Emmanuel did really a great job with the BV spec. And yes, *les castcodeurs* is a nice podcast, I like it too.