# Spring MVC 3.1 applying Custom Validation according to value of a field

Tags: java, validation, spring-mvc

I have a bean with flowing structure

```
public class Payment {
private String payType;
@Valid
private CreditCard creditCard;
private BankAccount bankAccount;
}
```

The credidCard class

```
public class CreditCard {
@Pattern(regexp="(\\d{16})")
private String cardNumber;
@NotEmpty
@Size(max=40)
private String name;
@NotEmpty
private String securityCode;
@Future
private Date expiration_Date;
}
```

Like that The validation applied to Bank account class also.
Now What I want is If PayType is Credit then I need to validate CreditCard other wise I need to validate the BankAccount.
I know for this type we can write a custom validater like in the link [JSR 303 Validation](http://blog.orange11.nl/2009/08/04/bean-validation-integrating-jsr-303-with-spring/)

But in this case I need to write validation logic for all the field of the class. Can write some logic so that according paytype existing validation will work. That Just I want the `@Valid` annotation according type.
Please Help me

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3683007/annotation-based-validation-framework - may be this can help.

Comment: @Noofiz it's not useful for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got the solutions for the problem and I am posting the answer so that It will be help full to other. The logic is I need to provide a custom method which will return the object which I want to validate. Like below

```
public class Payment {
private String payType;

private CreditCard creditCard;
private BankAccount bankAccount;

@Valid
public Object getValid(){
    if(creditCard!=null && payType.equals("credit"))
        return creditCard;
    if(bankAccount !=null&& payType.equals("bank")){
        return bankAccount;
    }
    return null;
}  
}
```